# Using vector to populate JTable from a database and display checkboxes in the last column

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, jtable, tablemodel

I have searched all over and have yet to find an example that can help me... I need to make the last column of my JTable (which is populated by a ms access database) appear as checkboxes that are unchecked by default. The database I am pulling from has hundreds of records, however for our purposes I  have modified the code and database to be much simpler . All I want to do is make the last column appear on the Java gui as checkboxes that the user can check and ultimatley save the results. Maybe JTable is not the best way to do this?

For this code I have named the Access database clientEmployee and added four columns the last of which is named "active" and contains yes/no values (checkboxes in access).

Please help me as my assignment is due soon. Thank you!

```
This is the main Gui.....

import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class TheMainGUI extends JFrame {  

    //Elements of Notes Tab  
    private JButton buttons5[];
    private JLabel labels5[];
    private String fldLabel5[] = {"Client","Employee"};
    private JPanel p1d;
        static String sql;

public TheMainGUI() {  

//creates the main tab pane object  
JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();  

//adds tabbed pane to the frame   
getContentPane().add(jtp);  

//Creats all of the tabs

JPanel jp5 = new JPanel();//checklist tab

//This adds the tabs to the tabbed pane and sets their titles 

 jtp.addTab("Stakeholders", jp5);


        labels5 = new JLabel[2];
        buttons5 = new JButton[2];
        p1d = new JPanel();

        p1d.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4,5,5));

        jp5.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        for(int count=0;count<buttons5.length && count<labels5.length; count++) {
            labels5[count] = new JLabel(fldLabel5[count]);
                buttons5[count] = new JButton(fldLabel5[count]);

                p1d.add(buttons5[count]);
}
               buttons5[0].addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {

            //Handle JButton event if it is clicked
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                            sql = "Select * from client";
                            DatabaseForm.dbFrame();
                            //setVisible(false);        
            }
        }
        );   
                buttons5[1].addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {

            //Handle JButton event if it is clicked
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                            sql = "Select * employee'";
                            DatabaseForm.dbFrame();
                            //setVisible(false);        
            }
        }
        );   

            jp5.add(p1d);
}

     //Main method creates GUI
     public static void main (String []args){  
        TheMainGUI frame = new TheMainGUI();       
        frame.setTitle("Stakeholders");  
        frame.setSize(400,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
     }






This is the database form class........


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

public class DatabaseForm extends JFrame{

    public  ResultSet rs;
    public  Statement stmt;
    public  Connection con;
    JButton save;
    public Checkbox box[];

public DatabaseForm() {

    Vector columnNames = new Vector();
    Vector data = new Vector();

    try {
            // connects to database    
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:clientEmployee");

                //declare statment variable
                 stmt = con.createStatement();
                //declare result set and get query from the main gui
                 rs = stmt.executeQuery( TheMainGUI.sql );

                 //declare metadata variable 
                ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();

        //set variable colmns to get column count                  
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();

        //for loop retreives all column names from the database
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
        columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
        }


     while (rs.next()) {


        Vector row = new Vector(columns);

        //for loop that retreives data from the columns
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {

        row.addElement( rs.getObject(i));
        //row.add(box[i]);
        }
        data.addElement( row );


}
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
}
    catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println( e );
}
    //create JTable
            JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    // create scroll feature
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      // add save button
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                save = new JButton("Save");
                    buttonPanel.add(save);
        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

                 save.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {

            //Handle JButton event if it is clicked
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                   setVisible(false);
            }
        }
        );
        }

        static void dbFrame(){
            DatabaseForm frame = new DatabaseForm();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame.pack();
            frame.setTitle("Stakeholder Checklist");
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocation(450,50);
            frame.setSize(1000,900);
}   
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, and show use the relevant code: the code which sets up the table data.

Comment: To complete @JBNizet comment: remove all the database related code and just use some hard-coded data so that we can run your code without having to setup a DB (see [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org))

Answer (score 2):

Implement a custom TableModel which wraps around  a List (probably ArrayList not Vector).

Here is a read-only sample: http://puces-samples.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/puces-samples/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-sample/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/sample/ParticipantTableModel.java?revision=13&view=markup

Make sure the getColumnClass returns Boolean.class for the last column if you want a check box.

Make sure the cells you want to edit are editable (isCellEditable).

Tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: Do you have an example which pulls data from a database, I'm having trouble following the example and translating it to my code. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I recommend to use JPA to get a list of POJOs: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29
Otherwise if you're using plain JDBC you have to populate the POJOs manually or go for a data centric approach (list of list of objects) rather than an Object Oriented approach (list of POJOs).